# SystemTray.getSystemTray() error, can't Find a class

Tags: java, system-tray

i have a problem with my code. My IDE (NetBeans) shows that there is no such class like ".getSystemTray()". I was looking everywhere but i can't find the answer. Do you have any idea why it's going like this?

This line -

> final SystemTray tray = new SystemTray.getSystemTray();

Dosn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards

---

There is a code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DisplayTrayIcon {
    static TrayIcon TRAY_ICON;


    public DisplayTrayIcon(){
        SHOW_TRAY_ICON();
    }

    public static void SHOW_TRAY_ICON(){
        if(!SystemTray.isSupported()){
            System.err.println("Error, TrayIcon not supported!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        TRAY_ICON = new TrayIcon(CREATE_ICON("LogoOnTime.png","Tray Icon"));
        final SystemTray tray = new **SystemTray.getSystemTray()**;
    }

    protected static Image CREATE_ICON(String path, String desc){
        URL ImageURL = DisplayTrayIcon.class.getResource(path);
        return (new ImageIcon(ImageURL, desc)).getImage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was not aware of `SystemTray` class.

You need to remove `new` keyword and make like below:

```
final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
```

Comment: If i do it like this:
final SystemTray tray = new SystemTray();
tray.getSystemTray();

That shows me SystemTray() has private access in SystemTray

Comment: So what should i do now?

Comment: How i should provide SystemTray? It's still shows SystemTray() has private access in SystemTray

Comment: @mixer176 Please provide `SystemTray` class by editing your question. Seems `getSystemTray()` has private access specifier. Otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: I find sth on java docs but they did it the same way as i did it before.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

I'm in dead end

Comment: @mixer176 I was not aware of `SystemTray` class. Apology for that. You just need to remove `new` keyword. See updated answer.